# Extracting userid from Inbound headers

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2009, biztalk2006r2

I have to read element from Inbound Header...

I am assigning inbound header using WCF.InboundHeaders to a string....

now my problem is my inbounde header is looking like this

InboundHeaders

```
<headers><s:userid xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">testuser</s:userid>

 <s:applicationid xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">assistworkerweb</s:applicationid>

<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://Request</a:Action><a:To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
```

Now i need to extract user id from it ..how to extract user id from it..

Comment: You don't give enough explanation of your setup to understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't mentioned where or how your string is stored (that is populated with your WCF.InboundHeaders), however I would use a simple fragment of XPath to extract the UserId. If you were extracting this using a C# helper, you could do something along the lines of (note, this is untested, however its pretty much there):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load([WCF.InboundHeaders Xml Fragment]);

// Create an XmlNamespaceManager to add 'soap-envelope' namespace
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("s", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");

// Select the UserId
XmlNode userId = doc.SelectSingleNode("/headers/s:userid", nsmgr);
Console.WriteLine(userId.InnerXml);
```

You may also want to serialize the Xml fragment into a .Net object and retrieve the UserId in that manner.